Удаление ненужного списка товаров woocommerce
На сайте с woocommerce есть настройка "Страница магазина", она по умолчанию добавляет список товаров. Сейчас страница выглядит так:

Верхний список я добавил шорткодом, нижний (выделил красным) woocommerce добавил сам. Как его можно убрать?


woocommerce добавил сам.

woocommerce добавляет "сам" только в 2х случаях: если в страницу вставлен а) шорткод или б)блок.
Отдельная история - если пользователь или производитель темы вставил вывод непосредственно в шаблон магазина.
Отсюда вывод: чтобы это убрать нужно найти откуда оно берётся.
